# Can we manipulate maven's properties?

Tags: java, maven

Can we add something to a property rather setting value to it? For example in this section:

```
<properties>
<myCoolProp>text1</myCoolProp>
</properties>

......

<profile>
    <id>add-profile</id>
    <properties>
       <myCoolProp>text2</myCoolProp>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

I'm trying to get this property myCoolProp = text1text2.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why? What is the background of your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Could you elaborate, what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have a several profiles with that property, and, by enabling several of them, i planning on using maven-replacer-plugin to replace some text in certain file. And, of course, I wanted all combined strings from all enabled profiles to be in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different name for the base property, and you can control it all you want.

```
<properties>
  <myCoolPropBase>text1</myCoolPropBase>
</properties>

......

<profile>
  <id>add-profile</id>
  <properties>
    <myCoolProp>${myCoolPropBase}text2</myCoolProp>
  </properties>
</profile>
```